# How to keep hyphen in BibTex key title?

Tags: bibtex, formatting, citing, zotero, better-bibtex

I recently installed `Better BibTeX for Zotero` in my zotero (ver. 6.0.27) on Windows 10 PC.

Before installing it, the citation key was like

> author_title_year

where `title` included a hyphen.

For example, if the first word in the title is `hyphenated-title`, the citation key was like:

> author_hyphenated-title_year

However, after installing Better BibTeX and setting a citation key formula to be `[auth:lower]_[veryshorttitle:lower]_[year]`, I ended up getting the citation key without a hyphen:

> author_hyphenatedtitle_year

How can I keep a hyphen in the title? Is there an easy fix by changing `veryshorttitle` or `shorttitle`?

Comment: Welcome. I guess that some kind of RegEx behind those specific Zotero commands sorts out/replaces the hyphens. But for me thats not a TeX related question. You better ask in a Zotero forum or somewhere similar